# Best way to init replicated caches

Tags: caching, replication

I have a web application which use ehcache for caching. Now i want to run the application in two nodes (two Tomcats), and i decide to to use RMI cache replication, but i have some questions:

1) I have cache which is loaded on application startup (from database), and then used by the application (every change in the database is also applied to the cache). Now, when i have two nodes i have the following case:
a) Node one is started and cache on this node is initialized
b) Second node is starting up, its cache is also initialized from the database, and replication to first node cache is started (which is not needed, because first node already have those data).

My question is what is the best way to init those two caches, so that i have synchronized caches after both nodes are started up?.